# IIS Rewrite all filename to filename.html

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, server

How do i rewrite url of my html webpages so that users can access them without having .html in the URLs.

This means filename uploaded on IIS server is about.html at example.com
I want that file to be served on example.com/about

I want this for several files so I want a code that takes care of all the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this with static html files then the easiest way is through static rewrites.

Please see the following article http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Yes i need for static pages but the problem is i have hundreds of them. Do i have to write separate rewrite rule for each page manually?

Comment: Usually for this I would do a static rewrite map. If you don't want to go that route you can use the following code. This will basically take whatever URL you enter and attempt to find a file ending in .html. Place this in the system.WebServer section of your web.config 
`<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Rewrite HTML Pages" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^([^/]+)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:0}.html" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>`

Comment: I apologize about the formatting. Not sure how to fix that. To summarize, the code above will take /about and display /about.html etc...

Answer (score 0):

this URL Rewrite rule will add .html to any request url that has no '.' between the last '/' and the end of the url. So this will allow you to use urls with and without the .html extension.

```
        <rule name="Append .html">
            <match url="^((.*\/)?[^/.]+)$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />
        </rule>
```

P.S. Just watch out for folders and files where the name, minus the extension is the same. For example, if you have this file structure for the site:

```
/
    content.html
    content/
        index.html
```

Then when you request http://localhost/content, you'll get content.html, not content/index.html.